# How do I get \DeclareMathOperator to put the limit beneath?

Tags: amsmath, math-operators

[image]

I use at the picture above: 
`\DeclareMathOperator{\vo}{vol}`
And this is the complete line:

```
\[
\lim_{a}=\vo_{a}
\]
```

I can make that the `a` will be **below** the `vol`? (like the `lim`).

Thank you!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the starred version of the command: `\DeclareMathOperator*`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\vo}{vol}
\begin{document}
\[
\lim_{a}=\vo_{a}
\]
\end{document}
```